# I'm new to programming and learning C, my problem is about printing a letter from a person's name by their index

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    string s = get_string("Enter name: ");
    int n = strlen(s);
    int i;
    do
    {
        i = get_int("Enter your index: ");
    }
    while ((i > n) && (i != 0));
    printf("%c\n", s[i] - 1);


}
```

when I input my name "Hung" and put index number 3, it printed out 'f', which I don't understand, please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're subtracting one before printing.  `s[i]` is `'g'`, and subtracting 1 makes it `'f'`.

I'm guessing that what you meant for the last line to do is this:

`printf("%c\n", s[i - 1]);`